# private key .pem loaded into aws elastic beanstalk (ebs)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jsch, private-key, pem

I am configuring a Java application using eclipse which is then deployed onto elastic beanstalk using Tomcat. This application uses Jsch, which is a technology that enables the application to connect to another server (or instance) using a .pem file. The only problem I have is that I do not know how to load the .pem file into elastic beanstalk in order for it to be used by the application. In normal circumstances (i.e. when using an stand alone instance rather than ebs), the application would just reference the .pem file from where it was located in the filesystem. However with ebs, I'm unsure of how to load it in, or reference it, because ebs is supposed to be composed of multiple instances right?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, EBS (Elastic Block Storage) is an AWS product which is *very different* from AWS Elastic Beanstalk. If you start talking to people knowledgeable in AWS, don't use *EBS* and *Elastic Beanstalk* interchangeably. :)

Elastic Beanstalk is designed to run websites and web applications which you *deploy* to it. As such, you'll need to add the `*.pem` file to the application source code that you deploy. Your application should know how to access it from within itself.

Comment: Is it safe to put a .pem file into source code? Is it not considered a secret key?

Comment: No. It should not be stored in source control, but can be pulled from a secrets storage mechanism (e.g., AWS Parameter Store, AWS Secrets Manager, GitHub Actions Secrets, K8S Secrets) at deploy-time.